# Stretch noise value meanwhile keep it in range (math issue!)

Tags: c#, math, graph, calculation, noise

I implemented a simplex noise algorithm (*by KdotJPG: [OpenSimplex2S](https://github.com/KdotJPG/OpenSimplex2/blob/master/csharp/OpenSimplex2S.cs)*) which works fine, but I'd like to add a "function" which can increase/decrease the contrast of the noise. The noise method returns a value between -1 and 1 but the overall result is quite homogeneous. It is not bad at all, but I need to get a different outcome now.

So basically I should "pull" the value of the noise toward the range edges.. this will result more contrasting noise (more distance between the smaller and bigger values). Of course this change must be consistent and proportionally scaled between -1 and 1 (or 0-1) to get natural result.

Actually this is pure mathematical issue, but I'm not good in math at all! I'd like to make it more understandable to give this picture of two graphs:

[image]

So, on these graph the Y axis is the noise value (-1 is bottom and +1 it the top) and X axis is the time passed. The left graph shows the original result of the noise generator, and the right is the stretched version what I need to get. As you can see on the right graph everything the same but their values stretched/pulled toward the edge (toward the min, max limit) but still in range.

Is there any math formula or c# built in function to stretch the return value of the noise proportionally respect to the min, max values (-1/1 or 0/1)? If you need the code of the noise you can see it here [OpenSimplex2S](https://github.com/KdotJPG/OpenSimplex2/blob/master/csharp/OpenSimplex2S.cs) too, but this is irrelevant in my case, as I just wish to modify its return value. Thanks!

Comment: The code should be a part of question. Please refer to [mcve].

Comment: Well the question is not related to the code itself! I just simple need to know how can I stretch a value respect to a max min limitation... OpenSimplex2S code quite complex and I can't make a "minimal reproducible example", especially that it's full of math and I can't understand most of it, so I can't be sure which part is important... I mentioned the noise only to make my question a bit more understandable. Some question is just too general to specify a code snippets for it. It is a math issue which related to coding generally.